# Bash to rename files repeats previous filename in directory

Tags: bash

In the below bash processes substitution, if there are 3 files in a directory `/home/cmccabe/medex.logs/analysis.log`, the filename variable is set to where these files are located.

I removed the code, as it was not doing what I thought but included the `set -x` of the original `bash`. Using `declare -p mapArray` as sugessted by @Charles Duffy, printing nothing. I am not sure why the filenames repeat and can't seem to fix it. Thank you :).

**`set -x` result**

**two files in directory using `declare -A mapArray`**

```
+ declare -A mapArray
+ IFS=
+ read -r line
++ tail -n +3 /home/cmccabe/Desktop/QC/analysis.txt
+ : line=00-0000_Last-First
+ mapArray["${line%_*}"]=00-0000_Last-First
+ IFS=
+ read -r line
+ : line=01-0101_LastN-FirstN
+ mapArray["${line%_*}"]=01-0101_LastN-FirstN
+ IFS=
+ read -r line
+ : line=02-0202_La-Fi
+ mapArray["${line%_*}"]=02-0202_La-Fi
+ IFS=
+ read -r line
+ for file in '*.txt'
+ mv 00-0000_Last-First_fbn1.txt 00-0000_Last-First_Last-First_fbn1.txt
+ for file in '*.txt'
+ mv 01-0101_fbn1.txt 01-0101_LastN-FirstN_fbn1.txt
```

**text file in `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/percent` - there could be a maximum of 3 files in this directory**

```
00-0000_fbn1_20xcoverage.txt
01-0101_fbn1_20xcoverage.txt
02-0202_fbn1_20xcoverage.txt
```

**text file in `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/analysis.txt`**

```
status: complete
id names: 
00-0000_Last-First
01-0101_LastN-FirstN
02-0202_La-Fi
```

**desired result in `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/percent`**

```
00-0000_Last-First_fbn1_20xcoverage.txt
01-0101_Last-First_fbn1_20xcoverage.txt
02-0202_Last-First_fbn1_20xcoverage.txt
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) did you run script under `set -x`? That might prove informative. 2) Why do you assign to `filename`? It is unused, and the comment above it is misleading if not false.

Comment: I did not run `set -x`, but I will and added where `$filename` is used in the `tail`.  I will post back.  Thank you :).

Comment: I added the `set -x` and it appears to be an issue with the `mv` line, but I am not sure what the exact cause is.  Thank you :).

Comment: This question currently has a lot more moving parts than it needs to -- right now someone needs a copy of `analysis.log` to fully reproduce the behavior, and the *intended* behavior is not explicitly given. A proper [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be refactored to remove all the logic that already works; hardcode a specific value for `line` for which your desired output doesn't match what you intend, and lay out **explicitly** what the behavior *should* be, and how that differs from what it *is*.

Comment: ...after all -- you know what you *wanted* your code to do when you wrote it, but we're not mind readers -- we know only what the code *actually does* do, not what you intend.

Comment: I'd also suggest some additional instrumentation. For instance, after `read -r line`, you could add `: line="$line"` -- which will have no effect under normal circumstances, but with `set -x` active will display the line that was just read, content which is otherwise unavailable in the log.

Comment: (removing an unused assignment -- like *all* code not necessary to showcase the immediate problem) likewise falls under part of MCVE preparation).

Comment: By the way -- it's very notable that you're storing under `${line%_*}` and doing a lookup under `${file%%_*}`. These values are not guaranteed to be similar or comparable to each other -- the former trims only the last underscore, the latter trims **all* underscores. But we can't speak canonically to your data without actually seeing enough to reproduce, which is to say, this problem is still in unanswerable-without-a-MCVE space.

Comment: I apologize, I removed the input and output files to shorten the post, but they were definitely needed.  I hope I followed the MCVE. I will try out your suggestions as well. Thank you :)

Comment: I added the `line="$line"` and the original as well as the new file are read.  Thank you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139186/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-chris).

Comment: BTW, I suggested `: line="$line"`, not `line="$line"` -- `:` is the command also known as `true`; using it makes it clear that what you're doing is enhancing the output of `set -x`, vs something that actually changes the script's state.